# How to display checkbox meta array values one by one?

Tags: user-meta, array, front-end, meta-value

By `wp user frontend` I add some checkboxes to users frontend profile. When I use `echo get_the_author_meta('my_pet', $author_id)` output is:

```
cat| dog| hamster
```

And when I use this loop code

```
$pet = get_user_meta($author_id, 'my_pet');
if( $pet ) {
    foreach( $pet as $pets ) {
        echo $pets;
    }
```

Outoput is same. 
I want display values one by one, and after each of them display a paragraph about it. like this:

```
cat
some text for cat

dog
some text for dog

hamster
some text for hamster
```

HTML source of checkboxes is:

```
<label><input type="checkbox" class="wpuf_my_pet_1153" name="my_pet[]" value="cat" checked="checked" />cat</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" class="wpuf_my_pet_1153" name="my_pet[]" value="dog" checked="checked" />dog</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" class="wpuf_my_pet_1153" name="my_pet[]" value="hamster" />hamster</label>
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use PHP [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function and convert string into array using a delimiter `|` then you can use `foreach` loop.

Example:-

```
$str = get_the_author_meta('my_pet', $author_id);
$pets_array = explode('| ', $str);

if (is_array($pets_array)) {
    foreach ($pets_array as $pet) {
        echo $pet;
        echo 'somtext';
        echo '<br />';
    }
}
```